# If column A in file 1 does not equal column B in file 2, delete line

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have two files, and I would like to remove lines from File 1 where column 3 of File 1 does not equal column 2 of File 2.

File 1 looks like

```
1111    1111    exm-IND1-200449980  I   I

1111    1111    exm-IND1-201453487  I   I

1111    1111    rs4477212   A   A

1111    1111    rs3094315   A   A

1111    1111    exm-IND11-102094357 D   D
```

File 2 looks like

```
1   rs4477212   0   82154

1   rs3094315   0   752566

1   rs3131972   0   752721

1   exm2268640  0   762320

1   rs12562034  0   768448
```

Desired file output would be

```
1111    1111    rs4477212   A   A

1111    1111    rs3094315   A   A
```

File 1 is 2.4GB, File 2 is 21.8MB.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 9):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f2[$2]; next} $3 in f2' file2 file1
```

Comment: Brilliant! That sorted it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to remove lines from File1 where col3 is not equal to col2 of File2 then following would work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}($3 in a)&&NF' file2 file1 > output.txt
```

Comment: PS: `NF` is used to remove blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in python:

```
import os
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2, open('f3', 'w') as f3:
    s = set(line.split()[1] for line in f2 if line.strip())
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip() and line.split()[2] in s:
            f3.write(line)
os.rename('f3', 'file1')
print (open('file1').read())
```

**output:**

```
1111    1111    rs4477212   A   A
1111    1111    rs3094315   A   A
```

Answer (score 1):

#### sed & grep

```
sed -nr '/^$/!{s/\S+\s+(\S+).*/\\([[:alnum:]]\\+[^[:alnum:]]\\+\\)\\{2\\}\1[^[:alnum:]]\\+.*/;p}' file2>file3
grep -f file3 file1>output
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim). You can buy some RAM memory and give it a try.

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
let d = {}
buffer 2
for l in range( 1, line('$') )
    let d[ split( getline(l) )[1] ] = 1 
endfor
buffer 1
for l in reverse( range( 1, line('$') ) ) 
    if ! has_key( d, split( getline(l) )[2] )
        execute l . 'delete'
    endif
endfor
saveas! output.txt
qall!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim file1 file2
```

And it will create a file `output.txt` with content:

```
1111    1111    rs4477212   A   A
1111    1111    rs3094315   A   A
```